# Issues with complex Ctypes Structure

Tags: python, c, struct, ctypes

I've been porting some C code [FANUC FOCAS Library] to Python using ctypes.

In one of the most complex Struct I have to porting, I am not able to catch all the variables' values and I am not being able to find out the reasons.

**In C** (from FANUC's fwlib32.h)

```
typedef struct speedelm {
    long    data;
    short   dec;
    short   unit;
    short   disp;
    char    name;
    char    suff;
} SPEEDELM ;

typedef struct odbspeed {
    SPEEDELM    actf;
    SPEEDELM    acts;
} ODBSPEED ;

FWLIBAPI short WINAPI cnc_rdspeed( unsigned short, short, ODBSPEED * );
```

**Then, for Python I wrote:**

```
import ctypes

class SpeedElmT(ctypes.Structure):
    pass

SpeedElmT._fields_ = [
    ("data", ctypes.c_long),
    ("dec", ctypes.c_short),
    ("unit", ctypes.c_short),
    ("disp", ctypes.c_short),
    ("name", ctypes.c_char_p),
    ("suff", ctypes.c_char_p)
]

class ODBSpeed_T(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("actf", SpeedElmT),
        ("acts", SpeedElmT),
    ]

# import library
fwl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("/fwlib_path/")

fwl.cnc_rdspeed.argtypes = ctypes.c_ushort, ctypes.c_short, ctypes.POINTER(ODBSpeed_T)
fwl.cnc_rdspeed.restype = ctypes.c_short
```

**An example running it in C** (found at inventcom.net)

```
#include "fwlib32.h"

void example( void )
{
    ODBSPEED speed;
    short ret = cnc_rdspeed(h, -1, &speed);
    if(!ret) {
        printf("%c = %d\n", speed.actf.name, speed.actf.data);
        printf("%c = %d\n", speed.acts.name, speed.acts.data);
    }
}
```

**And, in Python I tried**

```
speed = ctypes.pointer(ODBSpeed_T())

r = fwl.cnc_rdspeed(h, ctypes.c_short(-1), speed)

if r == 0:
    print(speed[0].actf.data)    # This one returns the correct value
    print(speed[0].acts.data)    # Zero when not Zero
```

I really cannot figure out why **acts.data** does not return the expected value.

Does anyone can help me on that one? Many thanks.

Comment: Use `speed = ODBSpeed_T()`, `r = fwl.cnc_rdspeed(h, ctypes.c_short(-1), ctypes.pointer(speed))`

Comment: Thank you for your comment @CristiFati . Unfortunately, it did not solve the problem. Perhaps, it is something w/ the machines' configurantion rather than python ctypes. Thanks for sharing

Comment: Slim chance. What's the behavior now? Note that you now have to use: *speed.acts.data*.

Comment: The behaviour keeps the same: speed.acts.data = 0, when the actual value should be other than zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that the C code had `char` not `char*`.  The fields in Python needed to be `c_char` not `c_char_p` so the structure size was wrong.

Here's a test DLL that has the same interface:

```c
#include <windows.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define FWLIBAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define FWLIBAPI
#endif

typedef struct speedelm {
    long    data;
    short   dec;
    short   unit;
    short   disp;
    char    name;
    char    suff;
} SPEEDELM;

typedef struct odbspeed {
    SPEEDELM    actf;
    SPEEDELM    acts;
} ODBSPEED;

FWLIBAPI short WINAPI cnc_rdspeed(unsigned short a, short b, ODBSPEED* p) {
    p->actf.data = a + b;
    p->actf.dec = 1;
    p->actf.unit = 2;
    p->actf.disp = 3;
    p->actf.name = 'A';
    p->actf.suff = 'B';
    p->acts.data = a - b;
    p->acts.dec = 4;
    p->acts.unit = 5;
    p->acts.disp = 6;
    p->acts.name = 'C';
    p->acts.suff = 'D';
    return 7;
}
```

test.py:

```py
import ctypes

class SpeedElmT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('data', ctypes.c_long),
                ('dec', ctypes.c_short),
                ('unit', ctypes.c_short),
                ('disp', ctypes.c_short),
                ('name', ctypes.c_char),  # C code had char not char*
                ('suff', ctypes.c_char))  # ditto
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'SpeedElemT({self.data},{self.dec},{self.unit},{self.disp},{self.name},{self.suff})'

class ODBSpeed_T(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('actf', SpeedElmT),
                ('acts', SpeedElmT))
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'ODBSpeed_T({self.actf!r},{self.acts!r})'

fwl = ctypes.WinDLL('./test')  # WinDLL for WINAPI, which is __stdcall (matters on 32-bit Python)
fwl.cnc_rdspeed.argtypes = ctypes.c_ushort, ctypes.c_short, ctypes.POINTER(ODBSpeed_T)
fwl.cnc_rdspeed.restype = ctypes.c_short

speed = ODBSpeed_T()                               # Create an instance
r = fwl.cnc_rdspeed(333, 111, ctypes.byref(speed)) # pass instance by reference
print(r)
print(speed)
```

Output:

```
7
ODBSpeed_T(SpeedElemT(444,1,2,3,b'A',b'B'),SpeedElemT(222,4,5,6,b'C',b'D'))
```

Comment: Many thanks! Kudos! It worked on 32-bit platform (in 64-bit it still does not work)! I am running it in a container.

Comment: @dacori Is `sizeof(long) == 8` on your platform?  You may need to specify `_pack_=1` for your structures.

Comment: Yes it was. I was not aware that in most Linux 64bits long type is sized 8 instead of 4. Now it is solved. Many thanks for your precious inputs.

Comment: @dacori According to the FANUC website they do use packing, but they mention specifically pack(4) for fwlib32.  Check the fwlib32/64.h header files for packing commands to make sure you use the correct packing they specify.  If my answer was useful, consider upvoting/accepting the answer.

Comment: Many thanks. It was, indeed very useful. It saved my day. However, I haven't upvoted because I can't (I have less than 15 in reputation score) but I will once I have a higher reputation score :P