# Error in running function from dll python(ctypes)

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I am using Fwlib32.dll to connect to Fanuc CNC machine using python.
Issue in running a function(python) , although it connects to machine too.
And yes , its running in C code with fwlib32.h (same function).

I reffered below link, but could not solve my problem.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67671042/issues-with-complex-ctypes-structure](https://stackoverflow.com)

focas is dll object in python(ctypes) of Fwlib32.dll

In C (from FANUC's fwlib32.h)

```
/* cnc_rdtofs:read tool offset value */
typedef struct odbtofs {
    short   datano ;    /* data number */
    short   type ;      /* data type */
    long    data ;      /* data */
} ODBTOFS ;
```

My code in Python (from FANUC's focas Fwlib32.dll)

```
ip = "192.168.1.10"
port = 8193
timeout = 10
libh =  ctypes.c_ushort(0)

ret = focas.cnc_allclibhndl3(
      ip.encode(),
      port,
      timeout,
      ctypes.byref(libh)
      )

class ODBTOFS(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("datano", ctypes.c_short),
                ("type", ctypes.c_short),
                ("data", ctypes.c_long)]
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Point({self.datano},{self.type},{self.data})'

tofs = ODBTOFS()
ret = focas.cnc_rdtofs(libh,1,0,8,ctypes.byref(tofs))  # 1,0,8 are general parameter
```

ret variable is getting value 65528.
Hence, tofs not getting any data ( Getting (0,0,0) ).Support for error code not anywhere I got.
ret variable's need is to be a 0.

Comment: If it works in C show the *minimal* C code. Also show the exact prototypes for the two functions called and set `.argtypes` and `.restype` attributes of the functions called appropriately.  May need to set `_pack_ = 1` in the structure as well. Two shorts and a long will add packing. Check the size of the structure in both Python and C and make sure they are the same.

Comment: Are you using 32- or 64-bit Python? Show an [mcve] of the Python code. Code is missing.

Comment: `ret` of 65528 is 0xFFF8 (hex) which is -8 (2's complement of a `short` return value...setting `.restype = ctypes.c_short` would return the correct value). According to [documentation](https://www.inventcom.net/fanuc-focas-library/Handle/cnc_allclibhndl3) `EW_HANDLE(-8)` is `Allocation of handle number is failed`.